# Implementing view recycling with PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using the Pager adapter with some ViewPager.PageTransformer to make a stack effect when user scrolls through pages, I'm also trying to recycle my view, My problem is the z order of the view gets messy when I'm using recycled view.

example:

view pager starts with 2 view the first is above second,
user scrolls right -> thrid page rendered, user scrolled right first page destroyed and go to recycle, forth page generate with recycled page, now he(number 4) suppose to be below number 3 , but he is above.

I tried to played with the insertion of the views to the container according to the position of current page and last pages adapter asked to instantiate, but it didn't help

I also tried playing with off screen page limit without any success, every few swipes a view that suppose to be below a view comes above him.

Any suggestions?